# Accept hyphen when using `<C-R><C-W>`

Tags: key-bindings, the-silver-searcher, grep

I currently have this mapping:

```
" bind K to grep word under cursor
nnoremap K :grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:cw<CR><ENTER>
```

My `ag` setting in vimrc:

```
if executable('ag')
  " Use ag over grep
  let &grepprg = "ag"
  ..
endif
```

This works perfect for regular words, but say I put my cursor under the term `customer-segmentation`, This command gets executed:

```
:ag "\bcustomer\b"
```

how can I make it execute this instead:

```
:ag "\bcustomer-segmentation\b"
```

Comment: You can also use <ctrl-r><ctrl-a>

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Yep! But the problem with  `<c-r><c-a>` is that it also includes other characters, so if the cursor is on e.g. `"test-this"` it will grab the quote marks as well as the hyphenated words.

Comment: @Rich, you are right it is not a solution.  I tought it is a chance to make it known and it could help on some cases it might help ;-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I agree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward (if not exactly *elegant*) way to do this is just to temporarily set `iskeyword` to include the hyphen:

```
nnoremap <silent> K :let s:old_iskeyword = &l:iskeyword<CR>
    \:setlocal iskeyword+=-<CR>
    \:grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>
    \:let &l:iskeyword = s:old_iskeyword<CR>
    \:unlet s:old_iskeyword<CR>
    \:cw<CR>
```

Above, I did it with line-continuations. If you prefer, you could instead define a function:

```
nnoremap <silent> K :call MyGrep()<CR>

function! MyGrep() abort
  let old_iskeyword = &l:iskeyword
  setlocal iskeyword+=-
  execute 'grep! "\b' .. expand("<cword>") .. '\b"'
  let &l:iskeyword = old_iskeyword
  cwindow
endfunction
```

Comment: Excellent thanks! I chose the first way as it's faster on usage than the second

Comment: You _probably_ want `:setlocal`/`&l:`/etc., even if it may not be necessary

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Like you say, I can't think of any scenario where using `:setl` would make any difference, but I've edited it in anyway as a best practice.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I also added in `s:` and removed the completely unnecessary `:unlet`, both of which were in an earlier draft but somehow didn't make it into the actual answer.